# How does the BitConverter reconstruct bytes to a short

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

So I'm currently trying to learn more about endianness and how bytes are converted to shorts, ints etc.

And I figured I'd start simple, I'd start by converting a short `("30000")` into two bytes and storing it in a `MemoryStream`

```
private static void WriteShort(short constValue)
{
    _stream.WriteByte((byte)(constValue & 255));
    _stream.WriteByte((byte)(constValue >> 8));
}
```

and if I understand things correctly, I start by doing some bitmasking using the bitwise AND operator `&`.

```
0000 0000 1111 1111 &
0111 0101 0011 0000
```

Which would result in a byte that looks like this `0011 0000` and I would write that to the `MemoryStream`. So now the `MemoryStream` contains a byte array which looks like this `[48]`

I then write another byte, based on the same value `30000` but I bitshift the bytes to the right by 8 in order to get the left hand most 8 bits `0111 0101 (117)` and write that as a byte to the `MemoryStream`. So now the byte array looks like this `[48, 117]`

that part seems pretty clear to me, it's the reconstructing of the short which gets me slightly confused.

How come I need to do the same bitshifting when reconstructing the short? I think that question is somewhat related to my other question which is, how does the '+' operator convert '48' and '117' to 30000?

And how does the `BitConverter.ToInt16(_stream.ToArray());` know what bytes to shift etc to output the correct value?

```
private static short ReadShort()
{
    _stream.Position = 0;
    return (short)((_stream.ReadByte() & 255) +
                  (_stream.ReadByte() << 8));
}
```

The entire program

```
internal class Program
{
    private static MemoryStream _stream;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(117 << 8);

        _stream = new MemoryStream();
        short constValue = 30000;
        WriteShort(constValue);
        var v = ReadShort();

        /* True */
        Console.WriteLine($"Is Little Endian: {BitConverter.IsLittleEndian}");
    }

    private static void WriteShort(short constValue)
    {
        _stream.WriteByte((byte)(constValue & 255));
        _stream.WriteByte((byte)(constValue >> 8));
    }

    private static short ReadShort()
    {
        _stream.Position = 0;
        return (short)((_stream.ReadByte() & 255) +
                      (_stream.ReadByte() << 8));
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not the same bit shifting, but `<<` instead of ` >>`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but why do I need to shift to the left after shifting to the right?

Comment: To undo the "shift right" effect

Comment: Maybe it gets clearer if you calculate `48 + (117 << 8)` - or the equivalent `48 + 116 * 256` - with the Windows calculator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have two bytes,

```
0011 0000
0111 0101
```

Lets also zero extend both values so both are 16 bit values:

```
0000 0000 0011 0000
0000 0000 0111 0101
```

Just adding these numbers together would clearly not result in the original number. We can also see that `_stream.ReadByte() & 255` does not do anything meaningful over just `_stream.ReadByte()`. Shifting the last number however will result in

```
0000 0000 0011 0000
0111 0101 0000 0000
```

And we can see that adding or OR-ing these numbers together results in the original value. Note that `BitConverter` does not necessarily need to do this dance, it could simply use native code to copy bytes directly. When converting larger integers to bytes you may need to consider [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), since integers will be represented differently depending on platform.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! So when adding with bits, it's just the same as adding any denary number? 5 + 5 would result in a new number, 10. same thing goes for bits then? I guess it's confusing because one of the two has a bunch of 0's leading up to the first byte. I guess I should look at it as adding two shorts rather than adding two bytes? I hope I'm making sense over here.

Comment: In your answer you were showing two shorts being added, but the code states that two bytes are being added to create a short `(_stream.ReadByte() & 255) + (_stream.ReadByte() << 8));` which is what confuses me I believe.

Comment: @JohnA When bytes are added they will internally be converted to 32-bit numbers before adding. I omitted the extra 16-bits since they do not seem relevant. There are some details with regards to signed numbers that I'm not 100% sure about.